# mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: simplexml_load_string()

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Can someone tell me what is the reason I get this warnings all the time?

```
simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 3: parser error :  xmlParseEntityRef: no name in /var/www/..line 50

mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): &lt;titel&gt;Shiatsu ..on line 50

mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: simplexml_load_string():                          ^ in ... on line 50
```

mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in .. on

I do a simple:

```
$var= simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

on that line..

Comment: Is that the complete warning message?

Comment: Edit your question with the complete error message please.

Comment: I have edited the question :)